# Potty breaks during The Force Awakens

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens

Ok so this's going to be a different kind of question. My kids and are going to see the movie tonight.

I/we always have a difficult time deciding if "now" is a good time to run to the rest room. Since so many people have gone to see the movie, are there any good recommended potty break scenes where we can go and probably **not miss something important**?

Ideally, when there's a longer period where nothing happens, nothing important is shown on screen, and there's no dialog of importance.

Comment: Finally. A **practical** question to a real problem someone faces!!! A first for this site :)

Comment: @DVK dude you so made me laugh

Comment: .... and **I was being 100% serious**. From site tour: *Focus on questions about **an actual problem you have faced**. Include details about what you have tried and exactly what you are trying to do*

Comment: Opinion based obviously - but I found the movie to be unrelenting in pacing and action. It was fantastic. There really aren't many down beats. Maaaybee when they first get to the green planet but make it quick because there is some important exposition that will happen later.

Comment: @NathanK.Campbell so as soon as I see a green planet, RUN!!!!  ?

Comment: Honestly - I'd go 'pre-prepared' if you know what i mean and avoid a large drink during the show. It's good. Surprisingly good.

Comment: There's an app for that. http://runpee.com.

Comment: It might help to know what you want from the movie. I found the vast majority of the actual plot to be completely useless, so after that there's just the character development moments, the funny moments, the actiony moments, and the worldbuilding/exposition moments.

Comment: Just stick it out. The after-movie pee is the best pee.

Answer (score 26):

Use the [Run Pee app](http://runpee.com/) to select the next opportunity to safely take a bathroom break.

They have 2 pee times currently.  The first is at 51 minutes into the film when

> Snoke says to Kylo Ren, "We shall see, we shall see..."

And the second is at 1 hour 38 minutes when

> Finn says to Han [sic], "I'm in charge now, follow me!"

The app has synopses of what you miss by peeing at each time.

Unfortunately, without more detailed guidance (edit the question, please), it's hard to be more specific.  See DaaaahWhoosh's comment on the question for ideas on what kind of detail we need.

Comment: Finn says that to *Han*!? I thought he said it to someone who used to give him orders. It seemed more funny that way.

Comment: @AndresF. You're right, but I'm quoting them, so I'll just mark that with a sic.

Comment: Using your phone during a Star Wars showing is a great way to get thrown out for suspected copyright violation, isn't it? At least, they're very strict about that here in the UK.

Comment: I think the idea is that you look at the app before the film and memorize the key phrases. Then sometime during your break while at the restroom, you pull out your phone and read the synopsis. That way, you don't pull out your phone during the film.

Comment: @Thunderforge - Eww. Using your phone in the loo seems very unhygienic. Don't forget to bring hand-sanitiser.

Comment: @Richard You could just pull out the phone after you've washed your hands. Be careful if you try to read it while walking back to the theater though!